Issue running Quasar CLI project in local GIT folder
I am attempting to use Quasar CLI with Vite to set up a SPA. I have cloned my remote repository, and gone through the steps after running npm init quasar to set up the project. When I attempt to run quasar dev, I get the following message:
 App • ⚠️  quasar.config.js > invalid Vite plugin specified (cannot find it): vite-plugin-checker
Then the browser is opened, but the network dev tools show a 404 error and nothing loads.
I can ensure that the vite-plugin-checker exists in my package.json and node-modules.
I haven't made any changes to any files before running quasar dev. I have tried the following:

Removing the Vite plugin and running quasar dev.
Initializing the project again.
Running quasar build works successfully.
Deleting node-modules then running npm-install and quasar dev.

I have noticed that when I generate the project in a non-GIT folder, it works as intended.
Any help is appreciated!
